# Show that if $\text{plim } A_n = A_0$ and $\lim V(X_n) = B_0$ then $\lim V(A_nX_n) = A_0^2B_0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics, moment-problem

I am wondering how the sandwich formula of the variance is derived.

Assume $A_n$ and $X_n$ are two random variables in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A_n$ converges in probability to a constant $A_0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} V(X_n) = B_0$. How to show that $\lim V(A_n X_n) = A_0^2B_0$? This is generally stated in many textbooks. I am wondering if we do not need more conditions. Something like the $\nu$-th moment of $\lvert A_n X_n \rvert$ is bounded, for some $\nu > 2$. How to show the formula of the asymptotic variance of $A_n X_n$?

Comment: Why is $V(A_nX_n)$ finite?

Comment: We can assume that it is. Maybe this is one of the conditions we should impose? Is it the only one?